# How to add facebook like button to VBulletin 4.2 posts?

Tags: facebook, like, vbulletin

The title  pretty much contains the question. I'm new to VB and could not find the hack, if any. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plugin http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=241011.

Generally speaking, vbulletin.org is a great resource for customizing forums.